# MathJax for a dummy

Tags: support, mathjax

After I made my first post here in math.stackexchange, I decided that I could write in the proper format and not rely on some poor soul to do the work for me.

I have downloaded the latest version of MathJax from the site and I have gone through every bit of documentation official and in discussion forums, etc but for the love of god, I can't figure out how to just make it work.

Every page I go to they talk about scripts and code..and I feel like am reading gibberish.

I am using windows 7 Chrome and I have no idea about scripting/code whatsoever. So could someone please explain in plain simple grandma-computer English, how to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: @DanielR Unfortunately i have already seen that. The situation is i have the MathJax files in the download folder and now what? I assume that i don't just write a question in MathJax format and it will magically know where to look to find MathJax. I will have to make some sort of connection between the browser and the MathJax files.

Comment: Maybe I'm not really understanding, but you don't need to download anything to make it work on math.SE. Just write those `$` signs around your TeX expression and it will be rendered for you.

Comment: @DanielR This is the part where i feel like a dummy. Somehow i though i had already tried that and it wouldn't work. Tried it (again?) and, success! Thank you

Comment: @Dim.Tsach. You don't need to download anything! The site already has MathJax so you just need to type your commands (don't forget the dollar signs) and it will automatically render for you. **No download required**